# Is it possible to play a video/frames relative to how much the user has scrolled in html?

Tags: javascript, html

So i have set up my own site and i was wondering if that was possible since i have this idea that would look really nice. I have tried to do it with Javascript but failed completely.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You need to show us your attempts to solve the problem yourself and explain how they failed. This isn't a free code writing service. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [MCVE]

Comment: I am afraid i deleted my attempts, but i tried it with getting the percentage of how far the user has scrolled and have it change the background image of my div for like every 5 percent. But somehow it only changed the image once when the user scrolled a bit and then i didnt even change back if the user scrolled back up.

Answer (score 0):

You can change video.currentTime, when the window scrolls. Like this:

```
let video = document.getElementById('video');

window.onscroll = function(event) {
  let currentPageOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  /* some actions with page offset */

  video.currentTime = ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks alot i will try integrating that